# How to convert a Array Object to EmberJS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I've the following class:

```js
App.Entity = Ember.Object.extend({
   id: null,
   name : null,
});
```

And I've the following controller :

```js
App.HomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  entities: null,

  init:function(){
      var myArray = [];
      var a = App.Entity.create();
          a.set('id',1);
          a.set('name','A');
      var b = App.Entity.create();
          b.set('id'2);
          b.set('name','B');

     //and I add another entities dynamycally

     myArray.push(a);
     myArray.push(b);

     console.log( 'isArray: '+ Ember.isArray(myArray) ); //I get true
     this.set('entities', myArray );
  }
});
```

The problem is when I try to iterate and render the content over view:

```html
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home" >
  {{#if entities}}
     {{#each entities }}
         {{this.value}}
     {{/each}}
  {{/if}}   
  {{outlet}}
 </script>
```

I get the following mistake:

```js
Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed     <App.Entity:ember425>,<App.Entity:ember426>,...
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Try `this.set('entities', [myArray] );`

Comment: @Andrei, Hi, if do `this.set('entities', [myArray] );` with this I put in the first position of entities one Array (`myArray`), no transform `myArray` to EmberArray(or wahtever that ember can iterate) then when I render my view I get `<App.Entity:ember423>,<App.Entity:ember424>,....` how to render the content of each value, `{{ this.WHAT??}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit in their documentation, I have understood that you should use `Ember.ArrayController` to render arrays.

An example from [their documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html) would be like this:

Controller:

```
MyApp.listController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

$.get('people.json', function(data) {
  MyApp.listController.set('content', data);
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each MyApp.listController}}
  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
{{/each}}
```

As can be seen here, they first set the *key* `content` with the `data` array directly on the controller. In your case this would be the step `this.set('entities', myArray );` that you already did.

In the second step, they use the `#each` helper on the controller, not the key. In your case this would look like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home" >
  {{#if entities}}
     {{#each App.HomeController }}
         {{id}} {{value}}
     {{/each}}
  {{/if}}   
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

To access the properties you do it as in any handlebars template.

#### Update

From your comments I assume that you are not deserializing the json string to a javascript object.

The json you receive from the server is a plain string. You must deserialize it using `JSON.parse`.

Example :

```
var json = '[{"id":"17","nombre":"Musical dezzer"},
             {"id":"172","nombre":"Musical dezzer"}]',
    trueResult = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(trueResult);
```

Comment: Thanks but not works,I change my normal array to json Array if I put in my view the same way that you and documentation show I get the following mistake : `Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed App.HomeController`. I attempted to do `{{#each content}}` and I get the following mistake: `--- ember.js:3521
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [{"id":"17","nombre":"Musical dezzer"},{"id":"19",...] `

Comment: Now I get the fowlling mistake : ` Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed string`, the thing is that I use ajax function to call the my webservice from php I use return json_encode($json); to return my data , But this is a SOAP web service

Comment: Got some time and updated the post as per your last comments.